# What would be the derivation of the formula r=l/(1+ecosx) .

Tags: euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

The 'r' represents the distance of a point on the ellipse with respect to the focus.
The 'l' represents the semi latus rectum of the ellipse.
The 'x' represents the angle at the focus and 'e' is the eccentricity of the ellipse.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: From which definition of ellipses would you like us to derive this polar equation?